# Make a new pandas series between two indexes of of other series

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have the following Series:

```
x = pd.Series([1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1])
print(x)

0    1
1    1
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    0
7    0
8    1
9    1
```

I would like to filter out the first and last rows with ones and zeros (i.e. keep a series from the first until the last zero). To find the index of the first and last zero I perform the following:

```
zeros = x[x.eq(0)]  
from = zeros.first_valid_index()  
to = zeros.last_valid_index()
```

Now I would like to make a new series which consists of the data in between `from` and `to`, i.e.:

```
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    0
7    0
```

Anyone knows how to perform this last step? Or to perform the total method in a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.loc.html) with change `from` to `f` because `from` is builtins, solution working if exist at least one `0` value in data:

```
zeros = x[x.eq(0)]  
f = zeros.first_valid_index()  
to = zeros.last_valid_index()

y = x.loc[f:to]
print (y)
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    0
7    0
dtype: int64
```

General solution also working if no `0` values:

```
m = x.eq(0)
y = x[(m.cumsum() * m[::-1].cumsum()).ne(0)]
print (y)
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    0
7    0
dtype: int64
```

---

```
x = pd.Series([1,1,1])

zeros = x[x.eq(0)]  
f = zeros.first_valid_index()  
to = zeros.last_valid_index()

y = x.loc[f:to]
print (y)
0    1
1    1
2    1
dtype: int64

m = x.eq(0)
y = x[(m.cumsum() * m[::-1].cumsum()).ne(0)]
print (y)
Series([], dtype: int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

`from` is a keyword and it can't be used as a variable, use `loc`:

```
zeros = x[x.eq(0)]  
from_ = zeros.first_valid_index()  
to = zeros.last_valid_index()
print(x.loc[from_:to])
```

Output:

```
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    0
7    0
dtype: int64
```